# How to create Header "Date Range per Week" in Flexgrid

Tags: vb6, c1flexgrid

Help me to be able to suss out the problem on Visual Basic coding using the "C1 FlexGrid".

How to get a date range that would show the number of week as well?

For example:

```
   January 2003
 S  M Tu  W Th  F  S
          1  2  3  4
 5  6  7  8  9 10 11
12 13 14 15 16 17 18
19 20 21 22 23 24 25
26 27 28 29 30 31
```

I would like to show

```
01/01/03 - 04/01/03 as "week 1" of January 03
01/05/03 - 01/11/03 as "week 2" of January 03
01/12/03 - 18/01/03 as "week 3" in January 03 ... up "week 5", etc. ..
```

Is there a way I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not tested. Improvement possible. Make adjustments to code as per your requirement.

```
Public Function DateOfFirstDayofWeek(intCurrentDayofWeek As Integer, WhichDate As Date) As Date
    DateOfFirstDayofWeek = DateAdd("D", intCurrentDayofWeek * (-1) + 2, WhichDate)
End Function

Function dhFirstDayInMonth(dtmDate As Date) As Date
    dhFirstDayInMonth = DateSerial(year(dtmDate), Month(dtmDate), 1)
End Function

Function dhLastDayInMonth(dtmDate As Date) As Date
    dhLastDayInMonth = DateSerial(year(dtmDate), Month(dtmDate) + 1, 0)
End Function

Private Sub getWeekRange_Click()
Dim startDate As Date
Dim endDate As Date
Dim tmpDate  As Date
Dim dateOfMonth As Date
Dim myDate As Date

dateOfMonth = CDate("01/02/2013") 
endDate = dhLastDayInMonth(dateOfMonth)
startDate = dhFirstDayInMonth(dateOfMonth)
tmpDate = startDate

While tmpDate < endDate
    myDate = DateOfFirstDayofWeek(Weekday(tmpDate, vbSunday), tmpDate) ''Assuming Week starts with Sunday
    tmpDate = DateAdd("d", 6, myDate)
    If myDate < startDate Then
        myDate = startDate
    ElseIf tmpDate > endDate Then
        tmpDate = endDate
    End If
    Debug.Print myDate & "      " & tmpDate 'This Prints the Start date and End date of every week
Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: @it.bayu, you need to accept the answers that helped you. An answer can be accepted by clicking the tick mark below the up/down vote controls for the answer